# React Native Windows SHIFT + F10 developer tools has stopped working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, react-native

I was developing in react native for windows. To debug my code I used to open  http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ in my Chrome and press SHIFT+F10 in the app to open the Developer Tools and than Start Debugging.

However, SHIFT+F10 is not opening the dev tools anymore.
I'm running in Debug mode.

Does anyone knows how to re enable the keyboard shortcut or fire remote debug in another way?

I have tried to simulate the command using on screen keyboard, it does not work, although, ctrl+r works. So it is not a problem with keyboard.

**-> It is a React Native app for WINDOWS**

I run app using VISUAL STUDIO 2017 ENTERPRISE

Comment: solved: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/2052#issuecomment-452854268

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Emulator (IOS/Android) or Hardware-Device to Debug?
If you mean the Context-Menu in Emulator, here are the Shortcuts:

**Android**: CTRL+m

**IOS**: Windows-Key + D

If you have Hardware-Device you only need to shake the device.

Comment: I'm developing a React Native Application FOR WINDOWS. Thank you for your help, but these commands are for apps running in emulator

Comment: Ok, don't mind, that you develope "for Windows". Strange that anybody did, because Windows Mobile is official dead. But I think you'll have your reasons. Good luck with it anyway

Comment: It is an app for WINDOWS not for windows mobile. :D

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have got an answer back from Microsoft already, so just sharing it for anyone here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/2052

Essentially, there appears to have been a regression, and there is a patch to a React source file that fixes it.